# Field extensions with one algebraic and one transcendental element

Tags: linear-algebra, galois-theory

Suppose you have a field $K$ with $a,b \not\in K$ where $a$ is algebraic and $b$ is transcendental. I want to prove that there is no $c \in K(a,b)$ s.t. $K(c)=K(a,b)$. In the case that $b$ is algebraic over $K(a)$ then I have a contradiction which works as I can show that $[K(c):K]$ would need to be both finite and infinite using two different 'extension chains', however in the case that $b$ remains transcendental over $K(a) $, I cannot find the contradiction. Any help welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean $a$ is algebraic over $K$ otherwise the statement is false. if $c$ is algebraic over $K$ then by looking at the degree of the extensions we get a contradiction. If $c$ is transcendental then there is no $a\in K(c)/K$ such that $a$ is algebraic: because $c$ is transcendental you have a map $deg:K(c)\to \mathbb{Z}$ and if $a\not\in K$ then $deg(a)>0$ now if $f(a)=0$ and $f$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, then $deg(f(a))=ndeg(a)>0$ which is a contradiction.